# Generate pdf from current document

Tags: coldfusion, pdf-generation

I need a way to dynamicly generate a pdf from the currently opened coldfusion document. But I don't have an idea how to handle this because I didn't find a way i.e. to pass the current (html) text to a function which generates the pdf by using the cfdocument tag.

Any hints or ideas, how to solve this problem?

Comment: Are you using any particular framework (Fusebox, CF on Wheels, etc...)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than capture the current response body, you could use the "src" attribute of cfdocument to request the current page via an internal self-referencing request.

within Application.cfc:

```
<cffunction name="onRequestStart">

  <cfif IsDefined("url.showAsPDF") AND 
        url.showAsPDF IS "true" AND 
        cgi.http_user_agent IS NOT "ColdFusion">

    <cfset myURL = 
        "http" & 
         (IsDefined('CGI.HTTPS') AND CGI.HTTPS IS "On") ? "s" :  "") &
         "://#cgi.server_name#:#cgi.SERVER_PORT##cgi.script_name#?#cgi.query_string#">

    <cfdocument src="#myURL#" format="PDF"></cfdocument><cfabort>

  </cfif>
</cffunction>
```

This will look for the presence of a URL parameter named "showAsPDF".  When it is defined and set to "true", then this code will take over and run the same request internally, routed through a call to cfdocument.  The response will then be output as a PDF document.

Answer (score 3):

I did something like this before:

```
<cfsavecontent variable="pdf">  
    <table>
      ...lots of html and CF code ...
    </table>    

</cfsavecontent>

<cfdocument format="PDF" encryption="NONE">
  <cfdocumentsection>
    <cfoutput>#pdf#</cfoutput>
      <cfdocumentitem type="footer"> 
        <cfoutput>
          #cfdocument.currentpagenumber# of #cfdocument.totalpagecount#
        </cfoutput>
      </cfdocumentitem> 
 </cfdocumentsection>
</cfdocument>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can generate a pdf from basic html by using [cfpdf](http://livedocs.adobe.com/coldfusion/8/htmldocs/help.html?content=Tags_p-q_02.html)

You can even specify your cfdocument as source for cfpdf:

```
<cfpdf action="write" source="someCfDocument" destination="myBook1.pdf" overwrite="yes">
```

Example without a cfdocument:

```
<cfpdf action="write" destination="myBook1.pdf" overwrite="yes">
    <p>My dynamic html goes here</p>
</cfpdf>
```