# Generate pdf in coldfusion with current form inputs

Tags: coldfusion, pdf-generation

We have a form with a dynamic running totals table beneath the form.  For example, when a user changes a value in the Quantity field, the running totals update based on the input (via javascript).  The table is displayed only, nothing is saved in the database

We want to be able to generate a pdf that includes the updated running totals.  Basically I'm searching if there is some way to pass the current `innerHTML` within a div to a pdf.

This may have been already asked and answered here- [Generate pdf from current document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9296371/generate-pdf-from-current-document?rq=1) , but the user didn't specifically say that the form updates data after the initial page load. So I just want to be sure I'm not missing something. Thanks.   I have a feeling I should look into `localStorage` for this.

Comment: I think you may be over-complicating the PDF functionality. It is not necessary to keep up with the local changes that the users make as far as a PDF is concerned. Most likely they will make whatever changes to the page and then click a link/button to generate a PDF only after completing all changes. At that point you could submit a form with all of the updated values to ColdFusion and generate your PDF file. Instead of/or in conjunction with updating the innerHTML of a div, update hidden form fields.

Comment: If you tried hard enough, you could write to your database and create files without having your user submit the form, but I think it's a bad idea.  How will your program know that the user is satisfied with what he entered into each control?

Comment: @Miguel-F: You should make that a proper answer. Thats pretty much what I was going to write as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

(From the comments)

I think you may be over-complicating the PDF functionality. It is not necessary to keep up with the local changes that the users make as far as generating a PDF is concerned. Most likely the users will make whatever changes to the page and then click a link/button to generate a PDF only after completing all of the changes. At that point you could simply submit a form with all of the updated values to ColdFusion and generate your PDF file. Instead of/or in conjunction with updating the `innerHTML` of a div, update the hidden form fields as well.  Then on the ColdFusion server you could use something like the [CFDocument](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-7c21.html) tag to create your PDF from the form fields that were submitted. (Remember to validate all of the form field data before using it.)

Comment: Thanks all. I used the hidden form field solution. A co-worker suggested just copying the innerHTML of the display table and passing it as a hidden form field.  It seemed a bit odd to use a hidden form field to pass a long text string like that, but it works fine. The form is submitted via post, so length of the hidden form field isn't an issue.

Comment: *seemed a bit odd to use a hidden form field to pass a long text string like that* Um... why are you doing that? Just submit the text fields (quantity, etectera) to the action page, and re-calculate the totals with CF code, instead of javascript. Then use the total in your `cfdocument` code.